# Symfony 3 Collection of Forms not persisting foreign key

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms, symfony-3.1

I Embed a Collection of Forms. When I am adding a new record, foreign key is always null.

Does someone knows where is the problem? I tried to loop over results and persist each record but foreign key is still null.

Controller:

```
 public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        $bus = new BusVehicles();
        $busAmenities = new BusVehiclesAmenities();
       // dump ($busAmenities);
        //   $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($busAmenities);
        $bus->addBusVehiclesAmenities($busAmenities);
        $form = $this->createForm(BusVehiclesType::class, $bus);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $form->get('busVehiclesAmenities')->getData()->map(
                function ($amenities) use ($em, $bus) {

                    $bus->addBusVehiclesAmenities($amenities);
                    $em->persist($amenities);
                }
            );
         //   $em->persist($form->get('busVehiclesAmenities')->getData());
            $em->persist($bus);


            // Adding flash message to our user

            $this->addFlash('success', 'admin.bus.created');


            //  return $this->redirectToRoute('bus_add');

        }
        return [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ];
    }
```

Bus Entity (Parent)

```
/** @ORM\OneToMany(
     *     targetEntity="BusVehiclesAmenities",
     *     mappedBy="busVehicles",
     *     cascade={"persist"}
     * )
     *
     */

    private $busVehiclesAmenities;

    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->busVehiclesAmenities = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Add busVehiclesAmenities
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\BusVehiclesAmenities busVehiclesAmenities
     * @return BusVehicles
     */
    public function addBusVehiclesAmenities(BusVehiclesAmenities $busVehiclesAmenities)
    {

        if ($this->busVehiclesAmenities->contains($busVehiclesAmenities)) {
             return;
         }
        $this->busVehiclesAmenities->add($busVehiclesAmenities);
        $busVehiclesAmenities->addBusVehicles($this);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove busVehiclesAmenities
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\BusVehiclesAmenities $busVehiclesAmenities
     */
    public function removeBusVehiclesAmenities(BusVehiclesAmenities $busVehiclesAmenities)
    {
        if (!$this->busVehiclesAmenities->contains($busVehiclesAmenities)) {
            return;
        }
        $this->busVehiclesAmenities->removeElement($busVehiclesAmenities);
        $busVehiclesAmenities->removeBusVehicles(this);


    }

    /**
     * Get busVehiclesAmenities
     *
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getBusVehiclesAmenities()
    {
        return $this->busVehiclesAmenities;

    }

    /**
     * Set busVehiclesAmenities
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\BusVehiclesAmenities $busVehiclesAmenities
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
   public function setBusVehiclesAmenities($busVehiclesAmenities)
    {
        $this->busVehiclesAmenities = $busVehiclesAmenities;

    }
```

Bus Amenities Entity (Child):

```
/**
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\AppBundle\Entity\BusVehicles", inversedBy="busVehiclesAmenities")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="bus_vehicles_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $busVehicles;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\AppBundle\Entity\Amenities", inversedBy="amenities")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="amenities_id", referencedColumnName="id")

     *
     */
    private $amenities;

    /**
     * @var float
     * @ORM\Column(name="price", type="float", scale=2)
     */
    protected $price;

    public function __construct()
    {
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }


    /**
     * Get busId
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getBusVehicles()
    {
        return $this->busVehicles;
    }

    /**
     * Add bus
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\BusVehicles
     *
     * @return BusVehiclesAmenities
     */
    public function addBusVehicles(BusVehicles $busVehicles)
    {

        $this->busVehicles = $busVehicles;

        //$bus->setBusVehiclesAmenities($this);


        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove bus
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\BusVehicles
     *
     * @return BusVehiclesAmenities
     */
    public function removeBusVehicles(BusVehicles $busVehicles = null)
    {

        $this->busVehicles = null;

        //$bus->setBusVehiclesAmenities($this);


        return $this;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You mapped BusVehicle and Amenity as a bidirectional association.
The fk for Amenities is null because you don't set the BusVehicle for the Amenity.

You need to implement a method, say: setBusVehicle() in Amenities class:

```
public function setBusVehicle(BusVehicles $bus) {
    $this->busVehicles = $bus;
}
```

When using bidirectional mapping, you must set the objects from both sides.

Comment: A few tips: I would not use plural in Entity class names, it is a bad practice. And I would not use bidirectional mapping unless it is really necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Will fix class name ASAP and apply your suggestions.

Comment: Thank you for suggestions. I already implemented code you suggested and I can't event save to Bus table. It simply doesn't persist.

Comment: There is no error. It simply won't save to database. I get all form submitted data (checked using dump method)

Comment: I don't see in your code that you flush the $em. Do $em->flush() in order to save the entities.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139737/discussion-between-jureispro-and-duro-mandinic).

Comment: Hi. I miss copied it. Sorry for that. It does save but child table still have null as id (bus_vehicles_id is still)

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was not clear. You need to iterate over $amenities array elements and execute setBusVehicle($bus) for each one of Amenities, before you do the $bus->addBusVehiclesAmenities($amenities).